# How do I enable surround sound (5.1/7.1)?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have a logitech g930 (7.1) headset and I would like to know how I can make use of the surround sound in BF3 (5.1/7.1).
Which setting should I change in order to make it use the surround system and where do I find it?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You have a 7.1 surround sound system, and you're asking whether you should use the setting for 5.1 or 7.1 surround sound?

Comment: @SaintWacko "Where setting should I change in order to make it use the surround system?"

Comment: i want surround sound. How to do i do that? @SaintWacko

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, I did misunderstand. I've edited the title to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The setting you search for is in the audio settings of the game (*Pause-Menu -> Settings -> Audio*).

I personally don't have a usual surround system but built one myself:
I got a 2.1 Logitech system and just plugged my stereo system into the **rear speaker** audio jack on my motherboard.

It works just fine and now I can hear steps or grenades behind me - which really improves the battle-feel(d).

My audio setting is set to **Wartapes**. I guess it's just like any other surround setting, but you will notice it's a bit louder than the other options.

I hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta pick your favorite between Hi-Fi, Home Cinema and Wartapes. They're all supposed to work on a surround environment. Differences are

- Hi-Fi: High Fidelity, standard one let's say.
- Home Cinema: Sounds "like" a movie. Bass sounds are prioritized.
- Wartapes: Sounds "like" a Michael Bay movie. Louder and rougher, less attention to sound harmony and more to the sounds themselves.

They all sound pretty similar though, maybe the one making the difference is Wartapes.